# spring rabbitmq listener method invocation not working

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, listener

am trying to implement Spring RabbitMq with XML based instead of configuration file. The message is sent ( I can see it in the RabbitMQ Admin Management ) but the consumer is not printing any output. Consumer is initialized ( can confirm that the constructor is called ). Can you please let me know what is the problem with the below:

**rabbitConfiguration.xml**:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest" /> 

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  exchange="my.exchange" routing-key="my.test.1" />  

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue id="myQueue" name="my.queue" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange id="myExchange" name="my.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="myQueue" pattern="my.#.*">
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory" >
    <rabbit:listener ref="aListener" method="printer" queues="myQueue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="aListener" class="rabbitmq.MyReceiver"  />
```

**rabbitmq.MyReceiver.java**

```
Public class MyReceiver {

        public MyReceiver() {
        System.out.println("init..");
    }
    public void printer(String msg){
        System.out.println("message: " + msg);
    }

}
```

Here is **Producer code** in different Class:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbitConfiguration.xml");//loading beans
    RabbitTemplate rb = (RabbitTemplate) context.getBean("amqpTemplate");
    rb.convertAndSend("blah balh");
    context.close();
```

Comment: Are you waiting enough time between the context creation and the context shutdown?

Comment: Yeah, I tried placing Thread.sleep(1000); before context.close(). Still not working

Comment: As soon as I removed the `id="myListenerContainer"` (the XSD does not contains this attribute) and configure my own user and virtual host, your code snippet worked

Comment: I removed that as well, here is the snippet of my POM.xml `code`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>`code`

Comment: Also, when MyReceiver is modified to implement MessageListener , then it's listening on the overridden method onMessage. But my whole aim is to have object to be transferred instead of simple Strings; which is not possible by implementing MessageListener

Comment: Same pom and your code works. The only difference is the connection parameters, I do not have the guest user.

Comment: Try to increase the sleep and in the RabbitMQ Admin Management opens the queue to see if there is any consumers